# Consuming keys in dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I have the following

```dart
  <paper-input floatinglabel
    id="frequency"
    label="Frequency"
    type='number'
    inputValue='{{frequency.frequency | asInteger}}'
    validate='{{digits_regex}}'
    error="{{errorMsg}}"
    on-keyUp='{{consumeKey}}'
    on-mouseout='{{publishInstance}}'>
  </paper-input>
```

Given that the type is 'number', only when the key input is a number I would like for anything to be seen in the input field. How can I accomplish that with the consumeKey function?

I also thought that might be built-in in Dart. Is it planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent input on `on-keyup` you can only use `on-keydown` and your `consumeKey` method should look like

```dart
void consumeKey(KeyboardEvent e) {
  if(e.keyCode < '0'.codeUnits[0] || e.keyCode > '9'.codeUnits[0]) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

If you want to allow other characters you have to extend the condition to allow for example `-`  `+` `,` `.`

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Do you know if this is on the horizon to be included in Dart?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That you can only prevent the input on keydown is default browser behavior. You shouldn't expect this to change. Doesn't my solution solve your problem?

Comment: Let me explain, and this probably relates more to PaperInput. If a type is 'number', currently the input still accept letters as inputs. I was asking if the key consumption could be a part of the PaperInput widget so once the type of input is 'number' I would not have to code anything on my end, because the widget would have this coded already as part of the paper-element's core behaviour.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Currently this only validates (regex for example) when you leave the input element as far as I know. I would not expect this to change. Which characters are allowed in numbers  might differ from language to language. You can of course create a bug report in the JavaScript paper-input or maybe better core-input  repository (if there isn't one already).

Comment: Thanks, and also for current bwu-datagrid.